# PHP serialization of objects with lists of objects

Tags: php, arrays, object, serialization

I will be building three PHP classes where the first class will have an array of objects.  From what I have read this is no problem.  What I haven't seen is anything on is if the objects in the array also have an array of objects then will they also be serialized and `unserialized` properly.  Here is some sample `pseudo  code`:

```
class objA {
    var 1 = some value
    var 2 = some value
    array 3 = array(objB, objB, ..., objB)
}

class objB {
    var 1 = some value
    var 2 = some value
    array 3 = array(objC, objC, ..., objC)
}

class objC {
    var 1 = some value
    var 2 = some value
    var 3 = come value
}
```

Obviously from the reading posts and docs when `objA` is `serialized` it will also serialize the array of `objB's; unserialization` also works.

Is `PHP` robust enough to also `serialize and unserialize` the array of `objC's` contained in `array of objB`?

Comment: PHP supports the serialisation and unserialisation of nested objects, yes. There are no known limitations to this statement that I'm aware of. Have you encountered any?

Comment: Not having any problems, only wanted to know if it worked or if there was some sort of snafu that would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Is PHP robust enough to also serialize and unserialize the array of objC's contained in array of objB?

Yes. It will even run the serialise and unserialise magic methods on each object. As @deceze comment says, there are no known limitations and it's functionality that's been in PHP5 since inception.